# Changing dynamic table view cell data

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest, afnetworking

I have an app which uses AFNetworking to load json data (array of folders) from server. The app shows parsed data (folders) in table view and when user swipes table cell the app adds three buttons (delete, edit, cancel) to the swiped cell.

What is the best way to do following things.

1. When user taps "Edit" button in cell app opens new view to edit edit folder name. After renaming folder app uses AFNetworking to save new folder name to the server.
2. When user taps "Delete" button app confirms action and removes folder from server.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, set action for both buttons. You can call delegate method on view controller to Push/present a view controller where user can edit. And after taping on done, send a request to server with updated data. There should be a web page which receive and process your request.
Same is for delete, but you don't need new view controller you can just handle delete button tap and send a request to the web server with id of record to be deleted. And handle delete process from the web page in the web server.